# file lock leases via NFS v4 in C

Tags: c, linux, nfs, filelock

does anybody know how to use the fancy file locking features of NFS v4? (described in e.g. [About the NFS protocol](http://nfs.sourceforge.net/#section_a) (scroll down)). supposedly NFS v4 supports file lock leasing with a 45 second lifetime. I would like to believe that the linux kernel (I'm using gentoo 2.6.30) happily takes care of these details, and I can use `fcntl()` and it all comes out in the wash. I am guessing, however, that I have to do something special somehow to get, maintain, and release the lock lease. all help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are right, fcntl takes care of all this business for you. The lease management is done by the nfs client(kernel module in linux)

Comment: I like this answer for its simplicity. I am wondering how I know the NFS v4 voodoo is actually working under the hood, since fcntl will happily work on 'vanilla' local filesystems, and supposedly under NFS v3. I guess I have to try it and crash the client machine ;)

Comment: when the fcntl call hits the kernel it's dispatched to whatever file sub system that implements it for the file descriptor it's called on. If the file descriptor points to a file on an nfs mount, it'll end up in the fcntl function of the nfs client.

Comment: btw, is the NFS v4 lock lease via F_SETLEASE/F_GETLEASE or via the older F_sETLK/F_GETLK ? I would guess the former, but fcntl manpage is ambiguous, and google is not helping..